# Sticky footer sticks, but content won't

Tags: asp.net, html, css, sticky-footer

I have a sticky footer which works, but I'm using a tiled background image and an inner #content div. The problem I have is that the #content won't expand to fill the height of the container. I've got a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mpRUT/1/, where I've changed the colours to illustrate. The only thing keeping #content from collapsing into oblivion when the page is empty is the `min-height` set on it.

Can I get it to expand to fill the container, or do I just have to set a larger min-height and lose some browsers?

The effect can be seen at http://myfitzeek.lime49.com/

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand your question, since I don't see the footer being sticky. - I think you want to position the footer with `position: fixed;` and correct positions/margins; and set the `height` value to your `min-height` value. So you don't need the _min-height_ attribute.

Comment: I need the middle content section (white) to stretch down and cover the blue. The problem I have is that on the demo site (http://myfitzeek.lime49.com), the white background isn't expanding down to cover the tiled background image.

Comment: Ah, now the part below is colored blue, too. Now I understand the problem. Thanks. I'll look into it and see if I know better :)

Comment: You could use padding-top: 200px on your #footer (with z-index to 1 and #content z-index to 2). It's not elegant, but will achieve your visual effect.

Comment: @mdi The padding still overlaps the content (footer with low z-index cuts the right content [#content with high z-index]) for me, when I tested this on the website with firebug.

Comment: Because you should put position : relative to content for z-ndex to work. Maybe a margin bottom also, so the content don't overlap the footer in small resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### IMO: Will not work 100% without min-height.  (see comments)

#### My old answer:

Edited sample (as fork):
http://jsfiddle.net/4EtKh/1/

```
#wrapper: {
    /*min-height:100%;*/ /* remove! */
    position:relative;
    height:100%; /* new! */
    overflow: hidden; /* new! */
}

#content {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 140%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    /*min-height: 80px;*/ /* remove! */
    height: 100%; /* new! */
}
```

Comment: I colored the footer red to clarify the elements visually. - I also tested this solution on your page with firebug. It works.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is that I lose the ability to scroll the contents of #content if there's too much in it.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer. Didn't think of overflow working this way. Sorry. _I'm afraid I can't think of any other solution without using min-height, because `overflow: scroll;` is not what anyone would want. Otherwise your footer always will be at the bottom of the content, not at the bottom of the page, when the content is empty._

Comment: It was an excellent answer though, thanks for trying. I can't believe this is so difficult, I'm forever wrestling with footers.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that you're going to need to set `min-height: 100%;` and subtract the footer height using negative margin.

```
#wrapper { margin-bottom: -60px; }
#footer  { height: 60px; }
```

What are your target browsers? You express some concerns about min-height - why not design the footer to look acceptable if collapsed, so that it degrades nicely in an older browser? If you're using a sidebar in your finished design, you can use `.clearfix` techniques to force the footer to the bottom, which means it won't necessarily be noticeable.

Aside from doing `position:fixed;` on the footer and using a background image on your `#wrapper` to give the *impression* of a full-height content pane, I don't know of a way to make this work without using min-height on `#content` ([like this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)).

Comment: How would subtracting the footer work? I don't know how to do this since Echilon has mixed absolute (px) and relative (percent) sizes for the containers.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I phrased that poorly. The `margin-bottom` will need to equal the negative of the footer height. See [this example](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).